# What is a Yang-Gaudin Bose gas?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, bose-einstein-condensate, integrable-systems

I'm a mathematicians with interests in physics and mathematical physics. I have some kind of understanding of [Quantum Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_group) and I know that [Gaudin Models](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gaudin+integrable+model) are related to them in a way that I don't actually know. I have a general notion about superfluids and BEC and the two fluids model for BEC. Giving that background can anybody explain me in plain english what a [Yang-Gaudin Bose gas](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=Yang-Gaudin) is?